# Must I install ClockworkMod to install CyanogenMod on Samgung Galaxy SII?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, clockworkmod-recovery

I want to install CyanogenMod on my Samsumg Galaxy S II. If I install ClockworkMod I think I will void the warranty provided by Samsung.

Must I install ClockworkMod or can I just install CyanogenMod?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things are important here:

1.) Even if you wouldn't install ClockworkMod, you'd lose your warranty since you replaced the pre-loaded operating system with unsupported one.

2.) ClockworkMod (or any other alternative recovery) is what actually installs CyanogenMod on your phone so it is required.

In short: Replacing your phone OS with Cyanogen will void your warranty in any case. You'll need some way of installing CM and Clockwork is probably the easiest around.

Comment: ClockModWork only works with Cyanogen images?

Comment: Nope, pretty much all 3rd party ROMs prefer ClockWork Recovery as their way of installation - just point it to the .zip file.

Comment: Well, I know ClockworkMod is installed prior to CM, and remains on device with CM, but I wonder if it is possible to install CM instead of ClockworkMod, to boot CM directly? I know it's more convenient to have CWR installed, just I have a security requirement to disable CWR boot